# How to explain this ip routing table

Tags: networking, ip, routing

On my Ubuntu desktop

`ip route help` does not help me:

```
Usage: ip route { list | flush } SELECTOR
ip route save SELECTOR
ip route restore
ip route showdump
```

How to explain the following ip route:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0 proto static metric 20100 onlink linkdown 
10.42.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 
10.121.173.0/24 dev mpqemubr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.121.173.1 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr1 scope link metric 1000
```

is `10.42.0.0/24` source and `10.42.0.1` desitnation?
What do dev `cni0 proto kernel scope link src` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields mostly match the command-line keywords for `ip route add`; see `man ip route`.

> is 10.42.0.0/24 source and 10.42.0.1 desitnation?

The main value, `10.42.0.0/24` or `default`, is the destination that the route is for.

There is no actual "source" field here – IPv4 routes are typically not matched by source, only by destination. (IPv6 routes *can* be matched against both source and destination, but the field would be marked `from` in that case, not 'src'.)

`src` 10.42.0.1 is the "*preferred* source" IP address hint to use when this system is making connections to that destination. (Primarily used when the system has multiple IPs.) It has no effect when the system is forwarding packets from elsewhere.

`via` is the nexthop gateway that the destination is reachable through.

`dev` indicates the nexthop device (interface), as seen in `ip link` or `ip addr`. If a route has 'dev' but no 'via', it's a "local subnet" route or a "device" route or an "on-link" route; the destination is reachable without a gateway. For routes that have a gateway specified in 'via', the 'dev' field is optional and just specifies which interface the *gateway* is on (but the interface can also be determined by following link routes).

`scope link` also indicates that this is a "local subnet" route and that it can be used to resolve gateways for routes of higher scopes. For example, a route that specifies `via 10.42.0.1` without a 'dev' field would automatically determine that the device is 'cni0' by using *only* the 'scope link' routes (as route nexthops are, by definition, local to the link).

`proto` is a label used to indicate what software installed this route – 'proto kernel' means it was added by the kernel itself; when you configure an IP address with a subnet mask, you automatically get a "subnet" route for it.

(Routing daemons such as Bird or FRR/Zebra/Quagga use the 'proto' field so that they can reliably detect and delete their own routes without mixing them up. You can specify any 'proto' value you like, with the names defined in /etc/iproute2; by default manually added routes get 'proto boot' assigned.)

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of this entry in your routing table:

```
10.42.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1
```

Is as follows:

- ***10.42.0.0/24*** is the destination, this applies to any traffic going to destination IP addresses falling within the range of `10.42.0.0` to `10.42.0.255`
- ***dev cni0*** indicates the network interface associated with this route, which is "cni0." The route will use this interface to send and receive traffic (this interface seems to be a bridge to a networking for container https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/cni-kubernetes)
- ***proto kernel*** indicates that this route was automatically added by the kernel during autoconfiguration
- ***scope link*** indicates that the route is only valid for the local link or directly connected network (and is not routable on the public internet)
- ***src 10.42.0.1*** specifies the source IP address used when sending packets through this route